# Why are my input placeholders persisting and not clearing after hitting save button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-functional-component

I have three components, home, teamDetails, and teamManagement. My application so far is simple a collection of inputs that can add a new team to the array of team objects.

The functionality is supposed to be so that when you click on add team, the disabled attributes get removed from the inputs and the placeholder values get cleared as well.

The issue that I am currently having is that once I add the new team details in the inputs and hit the save button in my team details component, the input placeholders dont get reset to empty strings as expected. also after hitting save, when I click on another team in the list of accordians, that teams info doesnt populate in the input placeholders after a new team is added.

Home :

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


 

import TeamManagement from "../components/TeamManagement";

import TeamDetails from "../components/TeamDetails";


 

export default function Home() {

  const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState("");

  const [isAddTeamMode, setIsAddTeamMode] = useState(true);

  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([

    {

      id: 1,

      name: "FINANCE",

      teamLead: "John Doe",

      description: "finance department description",

      status: "active",

    },

    {

      id: 2,

      name: "NUTRITION",

      teamLead: "Mike Green",

      description: "Nutrition department description",

      status: "active",

    },

    {

      id: 3,

      name: "PROCUREMENT",

      teamLead: "Dave Brown",

      description: "Procurement department description",

      status: "active",

    },

    {

      id: 4,

      name: "EQUIPMENT SERVICES",

      teamLead: "Jim Jones",

      description: "Equipment Services description",

      status: "active",

    },

    {

      id: 5,

      name: "SITE BASED OPERATIONS",

      teamLead: "Steve Smith",

      description: "Site based operations description",

      status: "active",

    },

  ]);


 

  function handleTeamDetails(teamName: any) {

    console.log("details set");

    setTeamName(teamName);

  }


 

  function addTeam() {

    setIsAddTeamMode(false);

    setTeamName("");

  }


 

  function saveTeam(updatedTeamDetails: any) {

    const newTeamId = teams.length + 1;


 

    const newTeam = {

      id: newTeamId,

      name: updatedTeamDetails.name,

      teamLead: updatedTeamDetails.teamLead,

      description: updatedTeamDetails.description,

      status: updatedTeamDetails.status,

    };


 

    const updatedTeams = [...teams, newTeam];

    setTeams(updatedTeams);

    setIsAddTeamMode(true);

    setTeamName("");

  }


 

  console.log(teams, teamName);


 

  function changeInput(e: any) {

    console.log(e.target.value);

  }


 

  function cancelSave() {

    setIsAddTeamMode(true);

    setTeamName("");

  }

  return (

    <div>

      <Helmet>

        <title>Home Page</title>

      </Helmet>

      <h2>Hello World!</h2>

      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>

        <TeamManagement setTeamDetails={handleTeamDetails} teams={teams} addTeam={addTeam} />

        <TeamDetails

          teamName={teamName}

          teams={teams}

          isAddTeamMode={isAddTeamMode}

          changeInput={changeInput}

          cancelSave={cancelSave}

          onSaveTeam={saveTeam}

        />

      </div>

    </div>

  );

}
```

teamManagement:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */

import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Department from "../types/Department";

import { Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";

import Task from "../types/Task";

import "../css/app.css";


 

interface Props {

  setTeamDetails: any;

  teams: any;

  addTeam: any;

}


 

export default function TeamManagement(props: Props) {

  function setDetails(eventKey: any, teamName: any) {

    console.log("details set!");

    props.setTeamDetails(teamName);

  }


 

  return (

    <div className="team-management">

      <div>

        <h4>Team Management</h4>

      </div>

      <div>

        <button onClick={props.addTeam}>Add Team</button>

      </div>

      <div>

        {props.teams.map((team: any, idx: any) => (

          <Accordion key={team.id} defaultActiveKey="0">

            <Accordion.Item eventKey="0" onClick={() => setDetails(team.id, team.name)}>

              <Accordion.Header>{team.name}</Accordion.Header>

            </Accordion.Item>

          </Accordion>

        ))}

      </div>

      {/* <div>

        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">

          <Accordion.Item eventKey="0" onClick={() => setDetails("0", "FINANCE")}>

            <Accordion.Header>FINANCE</Accordion.Header>

          </Accordion.Item>

        </Accordion>

        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">

          <Accordion.Item eventKey="1" onClick={() => setDetails("1", "NUTRITION")}>

            <Accordion.Header>NUTRITION</Accordion.Header>

          </Accordion.Item>

        </Accordion>

        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">

          <Accordion.Item eventKey="2" onClick={() => setDetails("2", "PROCUREMENT")}>

            <Accordion.Header>PROCUREMENT</Accordion.Header>

          </Accordion.Item>

        </Accordion>

        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">

          <Accordion.Item eventKey="3" onClick={() => setDetails("3", "EQUIPMENT SERVICES")}>

            <Accordion.Header>EQUIPMENT SERVICES</Accordion.Header>

          </Accordion.Item>

        </Accordion>

        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">

          <Accordion.Item eventKey="4" onClick={() => setDetails("4", "SITE BASED OPERATIONS")}>

            <Accordion.Header>SITE BASED OPERATIONS</Accordion.Header>

          </Accordion.Item>

        </Accordion>

      </div> */}

    </div>

  );

}
```

teamDetails :

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */

import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Department from "../types/Department";

import { Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";

import Task from "../types/Task";

import { useState } from "react";

import "../css/app.css";


 

interface Props {

  teamName: any;

  teams: any;

  isAddTeamMode: boolean;

  changeInput: any;

  cancelSave: any;

  onSaveTeam: any;

}


 

export default function TeamDetails(props: Props) {

  const [updatedTeamDetails, setUpdatedTeamDetails] = useState({

    name: "",

    teamLead: "",

    description: "",

    status: "",

  });


 

  const getPlaceholder = (inputName: string) => {

    const teamObject = props.teams.find((team: any) => team.name === props.teamName);

    console.log();

    if (teamObject) {

      return teamObject[inputName as keyof typeof teamObject] || "";

    } else {

      return "";

    }

  };


 

  const resetForm = () => {

    setUpdatedTeamDetails({ name: "", teamLead: "", description: "", status: "" });

  };

  const handleSaveTeam = () => {

    props.onSaveTeam(updatedTeamDetails);

    resetForm();

  };


 

  return (

    <div className="team-details">

      <div>

        <h4>Team Details: {props.teamName}</h4>

      </div>

      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>

        <label htmlFor="teamNameInput">Team Name:</label>

        <input

          type="text"

          id="teamNameInput"

          placeholder={getPlaceholder("name")}

          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}

          onChange={(e) => setUpdatedTeamDetails({ ...updatedTeamDetails, name: e.target.value })}

        />

        <label htmlFor="teamLeadInput">Team Lead:</label>

        <input

          type="text"

          id="teamLeadInput"

          placeholder={getPlaceholder("teamLead")}

          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}

          onChange={(e) =>

            setUpdatedTeamDetails({ ...updatedTeamDetails, teamLead: e.target.value })

          }

        />

        <label htmlFor="descriptionInput">Description:</label>

        <input

          type="text"

          id="descriptionInput"

          placeholder={getPlaceholder("description")}

          disabled

          onChange={(e) =>

            setUpdatedTeamDetails({ ...updatedTeamDetails, description: e.target.value })

          }

        />

        <label htmlFor="statusInput">Status:</label>

        <input

          type="text"

          id="statusInput"

          placeholder={getPlaceholder("status")}

          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}

          onChange={(e) => setUpdatedTeamDetails({ ...updatedTeamDetails, status: e.target.value })}

        />

        <label htmlFor="teamMembersSelect">Team Members:</label>

        <select id="teamMembersSelect" placeholder={getPlaceholder("teamMembers")}>

          <option value="member1">Member 1</option>

          <option value="member2">Member 2</option>

          <option value="member3">Member 3</option>

        </select>

      </div>

      <div style={{ display: "flex", margin: "10px", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>

        <div>

          <button

            onClick={(e) => {

              e.stopPropagation();

              handleSaveTeam();

            }}

          >

            Save

          </button>

        </div>

        <div>

          <button onClick={props.cancelSave}>Cancel</button>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  );

}
```

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io

Comment: here it is : https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-goldstine-l2wqvp?file=/src/TeamManagement.tsx

Comment: @PauloFernando ive added the sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a lot of changes, the main point is that a placeholder is just to show some text in an input before it has a value, when it has a value the placeholder is not going go show anymore.

Other important point is that to control the value of inputs in React your have to use an [uncontrolled or a controlled approach](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-react-to-set-the-value-of-an-input) For this I am using a controlled one.

And instead of passing a name and filtering by that I am passing the entire team to the details.

One thing I could not fix is that the first time you click on a button you will get a console error "Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled" but it works even with this error

https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-field-f7vszd?file=/src/TeamManagement.tsx

**App**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import TeamManagement from "./TeamManagement";

import TeamDetails from "./TeamDetails";

export default function Home() {
  const [currentTeam, setCurrentTeam] = useState({});

  const [isAddTeamMode, setIsAddTeamMode] = useState(true);

  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,

      name: "FINANCE",

      teamLead: "John Doe",

      description: "finance department description",

      status: "active",

      teamMember: "member1",
    },

    {
      id: 2,

      name: "NUTRITION",

      teamLead: "Mike Green",

      description: "Nutrition department description",

      status: "active",

      teamMember: "member2",
    },

    {
      id: 3,

      name: "PROCUREMENT",

      teamLead: "Dave Brown",

      description: "Procurement department description",

      status: "active",

      teamMember: "member3",
    },

    {
      id: 4,

      name: "EQUIPMENT SERVICES",

      teamLead: "Jim Jones",

      description: "Equipment Services description",

      status: "active",

      teamMember: "member1",
    },

    {
      id: 5,

      name: "SITE BASED OPERATIONS",

      teamLead: "Steve Smith",

      description: "Site based operations description",

      status: "active",

      teamMember: "member2",
    },
  ]);

  function handleTeamDetails(team: any) {
    setCurrentTeam(team);
  }

  function addTeam() {
    setIsAddTeamMode(false);

    setCurrentTeam({
      name: "",
      teamLead: "",
      description: "",
      status: "",
      teamMember: "",
    });
  }

  function saveTeam(updatedTeamDetails: any) {
    const newTeamId = teams.length + 1;

    const newTeam = {
      id: newTeamId,

      name: updatedTeamDetails.name,

      teamLead: updatedTeamDetails.teamLead,

      description: updatedTeamDetails.description,

      status: updatedTeamDetails.status,

      teamMember: updatedTeamDetails.teamMember,
    };

    const updatedTeams = [...teams, newTeam];

    setTeams(updatedTeams);

    setIsAddTeamMode(true);

    setCurrentTeam("");
  }

  function cancelSave() {
    setIsAddTeamMode(true);

    setCurrentTeam({
      name: "",
      teamLead: "",
      description: "",
      status: "",
      teamMember: "",
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello World!</h2>

      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <TeamManagement
          setTeam={handleTeamDetails}
          teams={teams}
          addTeam={addTeam}
        />

        <TeamDetails
          team={currentTeam}
          isAddTeamMode={isAddTeamMode}
          cancelSave={cancelSave}
          onSaveTeam={saveTeam}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TeamDetails**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  team: any;

  isAddTeamMode: boolean;

  cancelSave: any;

  onSaveTeam: any;
}

export default function TeamDetails(props: Props) {
  const [updatedTeamDetails, setUpdatedTeamDetails] = useState({} as any);

  const resetForm = () => {
    setUpdatedTeamDetails({
      name: "",
      teamLead: "",
      description: "",
      status: "",
      teamMember: "",
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpdatedTeamDetails(props.team);
  }, [props.team]);

  const handleSaveTeam = () => {
    props.onSaveTeam(updatedTeamDetails);

    resetForm();
  };

  return (
    <div className="team-details">
      <div>
        <h4>Team Details: {props.team.name}</h4>
      </div>

      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <label htmlFor="teamNameInput">Team Name:</label>

        <input
          type="text"
          id="teamNameInput"
          value={updatedTeamDetails.name}
          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUpdatedTeamDetails({
              ...updatedTeamDetails,
              name: e.target.value,
            })
          }
        />

        <label htmlFor="teamLeadInput">Team Lead:</label>

        <input
          type="text"
          id="teamLeadInput"
          value={updatedTeamDetails.teamLead}
          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUpdatedTeamDetails({
              ...updatedTeamDetails,
              teamLead: e.target.value,
            })
          }
        />

        <label htmlFor="descriptionInput">Description:</label>

        <input
          type="text"
          id="descriptionInput"
          value={updatedTeamDetails.description}
          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUpdatedTeamDetails({
              ...updatedTeamDetails,
              description: e.target.value,
            })
          }
        />

        <label htmlFor="statusInput">Status:</label>

        <input
          type="text"
          id="statusInput"
          value={updatedTeamDetails.status}
          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUpdatedTeamDetails({
              ...updatedTeamDetails,
              status: e.target.value,
            })
          }
        />

        <label htmlFor="teamMembersSelect">Team Members:</label>

        <select
          id="teamMembersSelect"
          value={updatedTeamDetails.teamMember}
          disabled={props.isAddTeamMode}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setUpdatedTeamDetails({
              ...updatedTeamDetails,
              teamMember: e.target.value,
            })
          }
        >
          <option value="member1">Member 1</option>

          <option value="member2">Member 2</option>

          <option value="member3">Member 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          margin: "10px",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();

              handleSaveTeam();
            }}
          >
            Save
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button onClick={props.cancelSave}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TeamManagement**

```
import { Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";

interface Props {
  setTeam: any;

  teams: any;

  addTeam: any;
}

export default function TeamManagement(props: Props) {
  const setTeam = (team: any) => {
    console.log(team);

    props.setTeam(team);
  };

  return (
    <div className="team-management">
      <div>
        <h4>Team Management</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={props.addTeam}>Add Team</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        {props.teams.map((team: any, idx: any) => (
          <Accordion key={team.id} defaultActiveKey="0">
            <Accordion.Item eventKey="0" onClick={() => setTeam(team)}>
              <Accordion.Header>{team.name}</Accordion.Header>
            </Accordion.Item>
          </Accordion>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```